# Fedora 11 software update stuck

Tags: linux, fedora, updates

I just told the update notifier in Fedora 11 to install the security updates.  It downloaded everything and applied the updates.  Now the updater says Cleaning Up Packages.  Its been stuck there for at least 20 minutes.  What should I do?  Should I just let it go and see if it ever finishes, or should I try rebooting the machine?  Will I be left in a bad state if I do that?

It only gets stuck when there is a kernel update.  Otherwise, it updates just fine and finishes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tend not to use the frontend GUI for this reason on Fedora. Try sending the application a termination signal so it closes safely first (`kill -TERM` or simply use `xkill`), then give the `yum` command line tool a shot.

```
sudo yum clean all
```

Comment: Is there any way to know what it is doing?

Comment: The exact same thing the GUI is doing behind the scenes.

Comment: After trying that and then rebooting (one of the updates was a kernel update), yum indicates that there are no updates to install.